# Where does logging happen in the plugin priority

Tags: kong

I apologize for not testing this before asking the question, but was hoping I can get a quick answer as I'm evaluating multiple API gateway options.

If I add Authentication, ACL, Rate limiting, Logging, when will I not receive request and response logs?

Should authentiation fail, will the logging still happen, or does it need to pass all the steps, and get a response back from the service before it gets logged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging will happen for all the conditions. You can setup different logging plugins from the available list of the plugins. [Here](https://getkong.org/plugins/)

For example you can setup http-log and set the http_endpoint where you will receive all your logs. You can consume input in JSON on that endpoint to evaluate and process it further.

I am sending all my logs to elastic search and using kibana to visualize the log content. ( I am using http-log)

Comment: Thank you. Are you sending it straight to Elastic search from the plugin, or are you sending it to a queue service to buffer. I've read that if you push too much logs to elastic search it gets really slow.

Comment: Yes, I am sending logs to queue and then to elastic as my API server is very busy.